# No response from JSON

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am trying to retrieve an image from a folder in a server using volley. The application worked once, but all of a sudden when I run the application from android studio, I don't get JSON response and I get a blank screen

```
package com.example.alex.imagerequestapp;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageRequest;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView mImageView;
String url;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //refernce both the image and the url to the image in the netwrok folder
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
    url = "http://192.168.56.1:80/bio_data_test/images/summerfestival.jpg";

    //begin the ImageRequest
    ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }, 0, 0, null,
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
    // Access the RequestQueue through your AppConroller class.
   // AppController.getmInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
    AppController.getmInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
 }
```

Comment: try logging response

Comment: And you are sure that your WLAN is enabled?

Comment: have you added internet permissions in manifest??

Comment: Log your response and set error image to be sure there is something error 
`mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_load_error);`

Comment: @ Shree Krishna i have done that, it returns the error message instead. @Vivek Mishra  i have added internet permissions. do you want to see my android manifest file

Answer (score 0):

if you are using emulator and you have local server, use this IP Address `10.0.2.2`

you can easily load a image from its `url` to the `ImageView` using Picasso library, it handles network calls for you

example:

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(image_url).into(mImageView);


where, 
mImageView ===> is your imageView instance after 
image_url ===> url of the image on the server
```

to add the `Picasso` library  adding following code to the dependencies block in the `build.gradle` file like this

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

and you would be able to use `picasso`

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix this.. the url changed from `192.168.56.1/bio_data_test/images/summerfestival.jpg` to `192.168.56.2/bio_data_test/images/summerfestival.jpg`. I discovered this after running ipconfig on cmd. It worked after i changed the IP address.